# I found this code in the head of a website, i've never seen something like this before, does anyone know what it does?

Tags: html, meta-tags

Could someone explain to me what purpose this code serves? I found it in the source code  in the `<head>` of the page for this site http://blog.brianbeck.com/tagged/jquery

```
    <!-- Default colours -->

    <meta name="color:Top Border" content="#333" />
    <meta name="color:Site Title" content="#D53C2E" />
    <meta name="color:Link" content="#333" />
    <meta name="color:Link Hover" content="#D53C2E" />
    <meta name="color:Button" content="#ccc" />
    <meta name="color:Button Hover" content="#D53C2E" />
    <meta name="color:Post Title" content="#333" />
    <meta name="color:Post Title Link" content="#D53C2E" />

    <!-- Default social link text -->

    <meta name="text:Website Address" content="" />
    <meta name="text:Blog Address" content="" />
    <meta name="text:Flickr Username" content="" />
    <meta name="text:Twitter Username" content="" />
    <meta name="text:Facebook Username" content="" />
    <meta name="text:YouTube Username" content="" />
    <meta name="text:Lastfm Username" content="" />
    <meta name="text:Delicious Username" content="" />
    <meta name="text:FriendFeed Username" content="" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is something unique to tumblr

“Enabling Custom Colors

By including the special meta-color tags in your theme, users you share your theme with will be able to easily tweak those colors using their “Customize Theme” screen. ”

The meta tags are essentially used as variables which users can change. They are referenced by the Javascript code on the page to make them automagically work.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://chrismeller.com/2008/06/meta-name-color#comment-1114

Comment: Awesome, you guys are the shizzle... or whatever kids say these days.